# Does the Raspberry Pi 4 running Ubuntu/Server (22.04.1 LTS) support Android Phones (USB / MTP)?

Tags: android

I created an Raspberry Pi SDCard with Ubuntu / Server (22.04.1 LTS) and it did not mount my Android Phone files as expected.  I was using a Raspberry Pi 4 w/4GB of memory.

I double checked using the same phone and my Ubuntu desktop and that did work.  I saw new directories and files under /run/user/... .

I then installed gmtp and mtp-tools into the Raspberry Pi and rebooted.  The Raspberry Pi still did not mount my Android Phone.  A device with "mtp" in its name does show up in the Raspberry Pi's /dev directory each time I plug in my Android Phone.

Is there yet another package that needs to be installed?

Maybe a service needs to be started?

Comment: Similar question posted by OP on Ubuntu.SE: [Mounting Android Phone on Ubuntu/Server/Raspberry Pi not working even after installing gmtp and mtp-tools](https://askubuntu.com/q/1440051/331791)

Comment: Yes, but it is not a cut and past.  They are worded differently to addressed the different user groups.  Also, the  RaspberryPi.SE post was not made until 80% of the expected views (13 out of (currently) 16) occurred for the  Ubuntu.SE question.  It is odd that you found this.  Are you a Linux & Android enthusiast?  Perhaps you can contribute by answering the question?

Comment: I get the feeling `fuse` service has to be running - been ages since I've done any linux that would need such "automount" though

Answer (score 0):

The question is about mounting a USB / MTP Android Phone using using an Ubuntu Raspberry Pi distribution and did not specify auto mounting.  I found on the Raspberry Pi / Ubuntu / Server (22.04.1 LTS) distribution there are no Android Phone UDEV rules as was on my Ubuntu desktop distribution.  At which point I chose manual USB / MTP mounting as that would work for my application.

I found after installing the packages mentioned in the question and [android-file-transfer](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/android-file-transfer/aft-mtp-mount.1.en.html) that I was able to manually mount an Android Phone using USB / MTP.  Here is essentially what I was able to do:

```
$ mkdir /home/ubuntu/mnt
$ sudo aft-mtp-mount /home/ubuntu/mnt
$ sudo ls /home/ubuntu/mnt
'Internal storage'
```

... when done, I unmounted the Android Phone with the following command:

```
$ sudo fusermount -uz /home/ubuntu/mnt
```